# UIScrollView pauses NSTimer while scrolling

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, nstimer

I have a `UIScrollView` that has a series of labels which are rapidly updating numbers (every .06 seconds). While the scroll view is moving, however, the `NSTimer` is paused and does not continue until after the scrolling and the elastic animation have finished.

How can I avoid this and have the `NSTimer` run regardless of the state of the scroll view?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

An easy way to fix this is adding your `NSTimer` to the `mainRunLoop`.

```
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

To remove a timer from all run loop modes on which it is installed, send an `invalidate` message to the timer.

Comment: So with this I don't actually have to fire the timer, it's initiated when that line is executed, correct?

Comment: From the documentation: "You can add a timer to multiple input modes. While running in the designated mode, the receiver causes the timer to fire on or after its scheduled fire date. Upon firing, the timer invokes its associated handler routine, which is a selector on a designated object."

Answer (score 1):

for swift:

```
NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
```

Comment: `RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.common)`

Answer (score 0):

(**Swift**) An alternative: You can use a GCD-based timer system like this one:

```
class GCDTimer {

    private var _timer : dispatch_source_t?

    init() {

    }

    private func _createTheTimer(interval : Double, queue : dispatch_queue_t, block : (() -> Void)) -> dispatch_source_t
    {
        let timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, queue);
        if (timer != nil)
        {
            dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(interval * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), UInt64(interval * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)), (1 * NSEC_PER_SEC) / 10);
            dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer, block);
            dispatch_resume(timer);
        }
        return timer;
    }


    func start(interval : Double, block : (() -> Void))
    {
        let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

        _timer = _createTheTimer(interval, queue: queue, block: block)

    }

    func stop()
    {
        if (_timer != nil) {
            dispatch_source_cancel(_timer!);
            _timer = nil;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here's how you would use it:
    
    `var myInterval:GCDTimer = GCDTimer()
    myInterval.start(1.0) {
        println("lol")
    }`

Comment: If you want to make an update to a UI element using this timer, you must do this on the main thread, like this: `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
      self.myUIImageView.image = UIImage(data: data as! NSData)!
     })`

Comment: glad you found it useful!