# Timer that updates label running in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nstimer

I have coded a timer using an NSTimer that updates a label. The problem is that in the same viewcontroller I have a uitableview and when I scroll it down, the timer doesn't update its value so the user can "cheat" to stop the timer.

I think this could be easy to fix with a serial queue with CGD but I don't figure out how to do it.

Thanks in advance,

Juan

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090658/nstimer-not-fired-when-uiscrollview-event-occurs

Comment: You're right, sorry but I didn't find it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all keep in mind that you cannot perform UI changes in any other thread than the main thread. Having said that, you need the `NSTimer` to fire in the main queue, otherwise the program will crash when changing the `UILabel`. Have a look at this links http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=67 and this one http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop_Class/Reference/Reference.html

To my knowledge, if you schedule the timer in the for the `NSRunLoopCommonModes` it will ignore event updates and fire the timer jsut how you want it:

```
 NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                           target:self
                                         selector:@selector(timerDidTick:)
                                         userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
  [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

-(void) timerDidTick:(NSTimer*) theTimer{
    [[self myLabel] setText:@"Timer ticked!"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem if u run timer in main thread than when you scroll tableview its stop timer too. Solution is that you run timer in background and update GUI in main thread

```
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    //run function methodRunAfterBackground
    updateTimer1=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(updateGUIAudioPlayer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:updateTimer1 forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
});

    -(void)updateGUIAudioPlayer {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.label.text = @"your text";
});

    //but if you want to stop timer by himself than use main thread too like that

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             [updateTimer1 invalidate];
         });}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) timerDidTick:(NSTimer*) theTimer{
        _currentNumber =_currentNumber+1;
        //check if current number is bigger than the contents of the word array
        if (_currentNumber <=wordArray.count-1) {
            NSLog(@"_currentNumber @%i wordArray @%i",_currentNumber,wordArray.count);
            _RandomLoadingText.text = @"Timer" ;
            [self changeTextInRandomLoadingLabel:_currentNumber];
        }

        else if (_currentNumber >=wordArray.count-1)
         {
             NSLog(@"reached end of array");
             [timer invalidate];
         }
    }

-(void)changeTextInRandomLoadingLabel:(int)myInt
{
    _RandomLoadingText.text = [wordArray objectAtIndex:myInt];
}
```

//---------
   view did load

```
    _RandomLoadingText.text = @"Test";
    _currentNumber =0;
    timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(timerDidTick:)
                                           userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Answer (score 0):

To update the UI you need to use `OperationQueue.main`. Supposing you have a `UILabel`named timeLabel:

```
var timeInSeconds = 0

timer = Timer(timeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { timer in
        timeInSeconds += 1
        OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
            self.timeLabel.text = String(timeInSeconds)
        }
    })

RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .commonModes)
```