# How to show NSTimeInterval on timer label

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm Japanese so I'm not good at writing English.

So I hope people can understand what I'm trying to say otherwise I'll stuck for forever!!

I'm trying to create timer so I have object called **Food.h** which has:

```
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *text;

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSTimeInterval time;
```

also I have object called **CategoryName.h** which has:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *items;
```

and I am doing this on my **DataModel.h**:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *lists;
```

then on my **DataModel.m**:
    self.lists = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:20];

```
CategoryName *categoryName;

Food *food;

categoryName = [[CategoryName alloc]init];
categoryName.name = @"Spagettie";

categoryName.items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:20];

Food *food;

food = [[Food alloc]init];

food.text = @"Spaghetti";
food.time = 600;
[categoryName.items addObject:food];
```

all Food, CategoryName, DataModel are subclass of NSObject.

and, I have this method to set my timer's time:

```
- (void)setCountDownTime:(NSTimeInterval)time
{

    timeUserValue = (time < 0)? 0 : time;

    timeToCountOff = [date1970 dateByAddingTimeInterval:timeUserValue];

    [self updateLabel];

}
```

In my **TimerViewController.h** file, I put:@property (nonatomic, strong) Food *food;
so I do **TimerViewController.m** file :

```
self.title = self.food.text 

[timer setCountDownTime:self.food.time];
```

title will works for this but for my timer label, it won't show any error however my label doesn't change.

If I do

```
[timer setCountDownTime:600];
```

it works. So please tell me what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: You should probably post the `updateLabel` method.

Comment: Also check whether `self.food.time` has value or it is nil?

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I'm updating label inside method of setCountDown: but should I update label again?

Comment: Where have you assigned `self.food` property? I do not see that in your code.

Comment: Thank you guys! I'm doing @property (nonatomic, strong) Food *food; on my .h of timer view controller

Comment: I'm doing food.time = 600 so it should have value, no? Sorry I'm very beginner of Objective-C and I'm try to understand English.

Comment: I tried everything but still not working...

Comment: the problem is not in the code you posted --> post more code

Comment: If you have already declared `@property (nonatomic, strong) Food *food;` in your .h, then you are overriding it with a local declaration in your code when you do `Food *food;` Remove this line and always refer to food as `self.food` in your implementation file.

Comment: Sorry I add more code. Thank you for suggestion. I hope it make better.

Comment: @MANA You are correctly declaring property for `food` in `TimerViewController` class. But you are not assigning anything to it. In your code you should have somewhere `timerViewController.food = <something>` or in view controller class itself `self.food = <something>`. I do not see that done anywhere, so that property is `nil`(I think. Use `NSLog` to print `self.food` value). You getting my point?

Comment: Thank you Amar! I put  NSTimeInterval _times; on TimerViewController class and I did _times = self.food.time then I did [_timer setCountDownTime:_times] still does not work. am I not doing what you are saying? Sorry for not understanding! but I appreciate your help.

Comment: I checked with writing NSLog and now I know I'm passing nil value but I don't know how I can fix it.

Comment: You need to use something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16261742/2713079)