# Call an action at specific intervals in iOS

Tags: ios, nstimer, cocos3d

I am trying to invoke a function that contains **ccactioninterval** in **Cocos3d**. I want to call that function at specific time intervals.When I tried **NSTimer** , i found that it works sometimes and sometimes not.

```
      NSTimer makeTarget=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(createTargets) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Here createTargets is the function that contains action events. when i run the function straightit works fine for single time. Problem comes when i try to schedule it. I ve tried different methods already explained for related questions . But nothing worked for me. . . .

Here is the code

```
-(void) addTargets {      
    NSTimer *makeTarget = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
              target:self selector:@selector(createTargets) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; 
}

-(void)createTargets {
    CC3MeshNode *target = (CC3MeshNode*)[self getNodeNamed: @"obj1"];    
    int minVal=-5;
    int maxVal=5;    
    float avgVal; 
    avgVal = maxVal- minVal;      
    float Value = ((float)arc4random()/ARC4RANDOM_MAX)*avgVal+minVal ;          
    [target setLocation:cc3v(Value, 5.0, 0.0)];    
    CCActionInterval *moveTarget = [CC3MoveBy actionWithDuration:7.0 moveBy:cc3v(0.0, -10.0, 0.0)];     
    CCActionInterval *removeTarget = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(removeTarget:)];       
    [target runAction:[CCSequence actionOne:moveTarget two:removeTarget]];   
}

-(void)removeTarget:(CC3MeshNode*)targ {  
    [self removeChild:targ];  
    targ=nil; 
}
```

Comment: What else did you try and what didn't work. Did you try `CCTimer`?

Comment: i tried scheduler and cctimer. call has been made but action is not performed

Comment: If the call is made but the actions aren't run I'd say the problem is with the actions, please show that code.

Comment: I ve used arc4random to set location of my meshnode. removeTarget function contains code to remove meshnode.

Comment: Have you debugged the method to check if `target` is found?

Comment: I gave counter in this method and found it s increasing continuously. So the counter seems to be working fine. When i run i can c only one meshnode moving, and at intervals a glimpse of another node comes as regular.

Comment: @KaranAlangat Please edit your question to include. 1) Your implementation of the `createTargets` method (+ any other relevant code it calls). 2) Exactly what parts of the code are being called and what parts are not beting called (use `NSLog`s). 3) What your symptoms are. 4) The context around creating your `NSTimer`, (are you creating multiple timers?)

Comment: I believe the code tells everything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without much code its hard to tell what you issues is, but here are some things to try apologies if any of this is obvious.

---

**Are you holding onto a reference to the timer?**

This might be useful for debugging.  If you have a property called `makeTargetTimer`, then you could do this:

```
NSTimer * makeTargetTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(createTargets) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
self.makeTargetTimer = makeTargetTimer // Save to a property for later use (or just use an iVar)
```

The only way to stop a re-occurring timer is to [invalidate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/invalidate) it.  Therefore you could check to see if its been invalidated.

```
BOOL isInvalidated = [self.makeTargetTimer isValid];
```

Also you might want to do this in your dealloc method anyway:

```
- (void) dealloc {
    [_makeTargetTimer invalidate];  // Stops the timer from firing (Assumes ARC)
}
```

---

**Are you scrolling when the even should be received?**

If you want the timer to be fired while scrolling then you need to use `NSRunLoopCommonModes`.  There is a excellent expiation in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9091524/296446).

```
 [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:makeTargetTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

---

**What is your implementation of `createTargets` like?**

- Have you put `NSLog` statements on the body of this method.  Are you certain its not being called?

Comment: thanks for your response . I have problem related to action. I have given a function to call. That function creates a meshnode and assigns an action to perform. I want that node with specified actions on specific intervals

Comment: My code has been given as comment @ Wain. So please have a look at it