# UIPickerView stops NSTimer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, nstimer

I've been working on a small app that contains only two elements, a `UILabel` and a `UIPickerView`.

The `UILabel` is updated by an `NSTimer` to count down from 60 to 0.

The `UIPickerView` only contains an array of data, don't interact directly with either `UILabel` with `NSTimer`.

My problem is that when I play with the `UIPickerView` and I scroll up or down, the counter "animation" stops, continues to make its action until you select an option from the UIPickerView.

I could not fix this, I do not know if it's a bug with the iPhone SDK or is there any property as becomeFirstResponder that can help me.

I'm using iOS SDK 6.1.

This is my code:

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>{
    IBOutlet UIPickerView *uno;
    NSMutableArray *numeros;
    NSTimer *timer;
    IBOutlet UILabel *contador;
    int num;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView *uno;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *numeros;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *contador;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize uno, numeros, contador;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    numeros = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [numeros addObject:@"0"];
    [numeros addObject:@"1"];
    [numeros addObject:@"2"];
    [numeros addObject:@"3"];
    [numeros addObject:@"4"];
    [numeros addObject:@"5"];
    [numeros addObject:@"6"];
    [numeros addObject:@"7"];
    [numeros addObject:@"8"];
    [numeros addObject:@"9"];

    uno.delegate = self;
    uno.dataSource = self;

    num = 60;

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateCounter:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [numeros count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [numeros objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSLog(@"Hi");
}

- (void)updateCounter:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
    num = num - 1;
    [contador setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",num]];
}

@end
```

The app looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pWpH.jpg

Comment: Try the solution provided in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059366/uiscrollview-pauses-nstimer-while-scrolling

Comment: @EgorChiglintsev **NSRunLoop** it works! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `NSRunLoop` after

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateCounter:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
        [runner addTimer:timer forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```