# NSTimer is not working the way it should while zooming

Tags: ios, uiimage, zooming, nstimer

This app uses NSTimer for triggering images at a certain timeInterval. This works fine but when you zoom in, problems start to occur, the timeIntervals between the images are not constant any more. I have tried two different codes for my timer and they both do not work.

```
_timerForImageTrigger = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:_timeIntervall target:self selector:@selector(automaticTriggerImage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

_timerForImageTrigger = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:_timeIntervall
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(automaticTriggerImage)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:_timerForImageTrigger forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

What I have done now is disabled zooming when the camera is in record mode. But this is not a solution I want to stick to. Are there any ideas how to fix this or where the problem could be?

Comment: automaticTriggerImage is called at correct interval but camera button is not get triggered? or Even the function also doesn't get called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSTimers are not guaranteed to fire exactly on time. I believe because your timer is on the main thread it is delayed by other activity on the main thread such as zooming.

This might be helpful [Stack Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18582662/xcode-objective-c-why-is-nstimer-sometimes-slow-choppy)

You might what to try running the timer on a background run loop.

N.B if you are updating the UI you have to do this on the main thread.

Also you might want to consider changing the tolerance (iOS 7)
[NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)

Comment: Thank you for the Link. Instead of using NSTimer I am using CADisplayLink, this made it possible, to keep fairly constant timeintevals during recording, even when zooming or focusing.