# NSTimer change interval performance

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, nstimer

My app adds a custom `SKNode` object to a `SKScene` at a fixed interval (sub second) using an `NSTimer`. At certain times I want the timer to *speed up*. Here's what I do (code simplified):

```
@interface MyScene : SKScene
@end

@implementation MyScene {
    MyNode *node;
    NSTimer *timer;
    int speed;
}

- (id):initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        speed = 0.8f;
        timer = [NSTimer = scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:speed target:self selector:@selector(addNodeToScene) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
}

- (id):addNodeToScene {
    if (node != nil) {
        [node removeFromParent];
        node = nil;
    }

    CGPoint location = //random x y coordinates using arc4random()...

    node = [[MyNode alloc] initAtLocation:location];
    [self addChild:node];
}

// at some point I call this method (called regularly throughout life of app)
- (id):speedUp {
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
    speed *= 0.9f;
    timer = [NSTimer = scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:speed target:self selector:@selector(addNodeToScene) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

I've noticed a slight lag every time i call `speedUp`. I'm very new to Objective-C so not sure how to resolve. Is it more efficient to use dispatch queues over a timer or can I not avoid this issue because the internal is so fast?

I ran time profiling on instruments and this was not highlighted - instead my heaviest method was `addNodeToScene`.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you're calling `-speedUp` outside of the normal work in `-addNodeToScene`. If so, the lag is likely coming from the fact that you've already used up a bit of the previous delay, then `-speedUp` invalidates the old timer and creates a new one, which starts the delay all over again. You'll see a lag any time you're more than 10% beyond the previous timer fire.

I'll try some ASCII art to illustrate. `+` is a timer fire, `*` is when you call `-speedUp` and it resets the timer.

```
+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
+---------+---*--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in another question: [Xcode / Objective-C: Why is NSTimer sometimes slow/choppy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18582662/xcode-objective-c-why-is-nstimer-sometimes-slow-choppy?rq=1)

(use `CADisplayLink` instead of `NSTimer`)

Comment: That maybe the source of some lag, but `CADisplayLink` is tied to the screen refresh rate. I'm skeptical that it will work well for what you describe, where you're scaling your timer interval down in some steps.